# Proof using binomial coeff

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I don't understand the step between left side and right side of my ?

I [image]

Comment: Posting math expression in images is discouraged here.

Comment: Maybe OP doesn't know how to use LaTeX?

Comment: @user117818, but OP's previous post suggests he can write LaTeX.

Comment: @boywholived Maybe I don't want to spend 10 min writing - with possible errors - when posting an image is just as good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bring the $e^{-a}e^{-b}$ "out" and divide and multiply by $k!$. We get
$$\frac{e^{-a}e^{-b}}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!}a^jb^{k-j}.$$
This can be rewritten as 
$$\frac{e^{-a}e^{-b}}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}a^jb^{k-j}.$$
We recognize that the inner sum is the binomial expansion of $(a+b)^k$. So our expression is equal to
$$\frac{e^{-a}e^{-b}}{k!}(a+b)^k.$$
The derivation quoted is a little more complicated. The author multiplied and divided by $(a+b)^k$, and got an inner sum of 
$$\sum{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^j \left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^{k-j}.$$
The inner sum is then the binomial expansion of $\left(\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^k$, that is, of $1^k$, so it is $1$.

Comment: On the first line $(k-j)!$ should be in the numerator, correct?

Comment: Thank you! There was a typo in that line, the $(k-j)!$ should be in the denominator. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different presentation:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a^je^{-a}}{j!}\frac{b^{k-j}e^{-b}}{(k-j)!}
&=\frac{\color{#C00000}{(a+b)^k}e^{-(a+b)}}{\color{#00A000}{k!}}\frac{\color{#00A000}{k!}}{j!\,(k-j)!}\frac{a^j}{\color{#C00000}{(a+b)^j}}\frac{b^{k-j}}{\color{#C00000}{(a+b)^{k-j}}}\\
&=\frac{(a+b)^ke^{-(a+b)}}{k!}\binom{k}{j}\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^j\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^{k-j}
\end{align}
$$
Of course, we also have
$$
\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^j\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^{k-j}
=\left(\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{a+b}\right)^k=1
$$

Comment: Color is very nice